# laravel queue works in postman but not in browser

Tags: php, laravel, postman, sendmail, jobs

I have an api that sends emails using a job, I test it in postman and it works perfectly but when I call it from a button (in another app calling the api) it does not execute the job. any suggestion? Thanks

```
public function test()
{
    $data['pass'] = 'FnJKfkuG';
    $data['name'] = 'Gordon';
    $data['route'] = 'myapi.test/validate-email/jQZSPFSZLuBqAdQofxtV5Bw2TK4ZcrNmoxFFR5ZvgGM48gHyKcxv7y6jHBaZhHIF';
    $data['email'] = 'abc@gmail.com';
    $data['title'] = 'Hi!!';
    $data['body'] = 'Text here.';
    SendEmailJob::dispatch('', $data,'','', $data['email'],'welcome');
}
```

SendEmailJob code uses sendMail function

```
sendMail($this->mailto, 'Confirmación de solicitud', 'newRequest', $this->data, 'mi correo');

function sendMail($mailTo, $subject, $view, $data, $from)
{
    try {
        Mail::to($mailTo)->send(new SendMail($from, $data, $view, $subject));
        return sendResponse('Ok');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::debug($e->getMessage());
        return sendExceptionError('Error 2',$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

SendMail is a mailable class

it works in postman with the route: myapi.test/api/v1/test, the job y executed and email is sent

but when I call this route from another project, it does not work

I try to debug it using logs, when use postman it works like a charm but when use it in a button it has an error: Expected response code "250" but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required". then, the job does not execute.

it is so weird, I dont understand why

Help me please, sorry my bad english

Thanks

I trying to send email using a laravel job

Comment: I mean... if you get `530` and the error is `Authentication required`, I am not sure what are you expecting from us without literally showing the button code calling the URL...

Comment: You might have to set the mail configuration in .env file, such as mail_host, mail_username, mail_password.

Comment: @matiaslauriti button code only uses guzzle to call api function thats uses SendEmailJob exactly how do test function above. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @Tinxuanna the configuration was rigth in the .env file and mail.php in the API project but I need to copy this configuration to app project, I dont know the reason maybe is a laravel bug I think. Thanks your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I copied the email configuration from the .env file and config/mail.php in the api project to .env and config/mail.php in the app project. I don't know if it's the best or correct solution, but it works now. Thank you all for the answers.

Comment: I am not sure how you are sharing your project, but if it is using Git, you will never track `.env`, so you were clearly missing the config.

Comment: Hi @matiaslauriti, both projects (API and APP (that uses API)) are running localy